# What does the following code mean? How is it used?

Tags: matlab

I looking for an explanation in a granular level to understand what the following code means:

`idx=y==100;`

From what I understand, it is taking a derivative of a variable x, setting it equal to y, equal to 100. Although, I'm not too sure what the purpose of this code would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `idx=y==100;` MATLAB performs the following steps:

1. It determines which of the two operators, `==` and  `=` is invoked first:
   Since the `==` operator has a higher precedence than the `=` operator, it selects `y==100`. To learn about operator precedence, you can have a look at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html.
2. The operation `y==100`, then compares `y` to `100` and returns logical array of the same size as `y` having `1` at position where `y` is equal to `100` and `0` at other positions. To learn more about the `==` operator you can have a look at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html.
3. Finally, MATLAB invokes the `=` operator: `idx=` assigns the result of `y==100` to the variable `idx`.